# Customise the defaults on Rails ActionText Trix Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, trix, actiontext

Is there anyway of changing the defaults on the Trix editor? For example; I might not need the undo and redo.

Currently facing an issue where i'm wanting to change the default Rails ActionText (Trix) editor. I've found resources online for adding a 'sub' and a 'sup' button into the editor which works but is there anyway of removing any? In order to add a button, you have to do this via javascript and listen for the trix-initialize event and then create all the elements and place accordingly however, in order to remove a button, when the trix-initialized is called, it's obviously initialized all the default config.

I've removed some of the buttons at the moment via CSS and just targeting the correct elements however, this seems to be quite hacky as the elements are already on the DOM and anyone that know how to use the Developer Tools, will be able to find it and could potentially do something that I don't want them to.